# Change Kendo grid row on click

Tags: select, grid, kendo-ui, row

I'm hoping someone can offer help in this.  I have a Kendo grid in a html document (no MVC), and am wanting to change the class of the entire row on row select.  I have tried various approaches, still with no luck.  I am currently at:

// within kendo grid definition - grid called '#grid'

```
    change: function (e) {
        $("#grid tbody").find("tr[k-state-selected]").css("color", "black");
        var id = $("#grid").closest("tr").css("color", "black");
        CallDocument(this._data[0]);
    },
```

The function CallDocument is being fired, and so I know I can at least get to the function.

EDIT:  Here is the solution that I came up with, and thanks to everyone

```
change: function (e) {
            $("#grid tbody").find("tr.k-state-selected").attr("class", "detail read k-state-selected");

    },
```

I needed to use the 'tr.k-state-selected' form, and change using attr in order to change the set of classes.

Comment: Can you break the chain and debug at selector level and do console.log or old alert to see if actual row is being selected. Rest looks fine i think selector is not able to reach that row. what is k-state-selected?

Comment: 'k-state-selected' in kendo is guaranteed to be the selected row.  So I should be able to scan the table looking for the row that has 'k-state-selected' and change the class.

Comment: so k-state-selected is a class on that row element tr? instead of tr[k-state-seected] you should use tr.k-state-selected in your find method

Comment: Thanks, and that helped with the solution I just came up with.

Comment: You can use jquery functions like addClass and removeClass instead of attr and that will not effect any existing classes and just add and remove class that you specify. For example `$("#grid tr.k-state-selected").addClass("detail")` will add this class to tr inside #grid and removeClass will remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mark every visited row as selected, you might add a CSS class on `change` event.

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    editable  : false,
    pageable  : true,
    selectable: true,
    columns   :
    [
        { field: "FirstName", width: 90, title: "First Name" },
        { field: "LastName", width: 200, title: "Last Name" },
        { field: "City", width: 200 }
    ],
    change : function (e) {
        this.select().addClass("ob-selected");
    }
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

The class `ob-selected` stays when you move to another cell since this does nothing to do with KendoUI.

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/2TGLp/1/

The only question is that it does not stay selected if you apply filters, change to a different page... but not sure if this is important for you.

Comment: I have gotten this to work now, and it was like you suggested.  I have a few classes associated with the current row, and so I put this on the grid change event: change: function (e) {
            $("#grid tbody").find("tr.k-state-selected").attr("class", "detail read k-state-selected");

            CallDocument(this._data[0]);
        },

Answer (score 1):

I override my Kendo styles using both css and javascript (depending on the scenario).

CSS:

```
.k-state-selected {
    color: black;
}
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
$('k-state-selected').css('color', '#000000')
```

Comment: Thank you, but to elaborate I will need to have the class persisted once I go to another row.

Comment: We can then add a class (e.g., `.black { color: #000 !important }) using javascript and use `!important` if necessary. This can be done by using `$('#grid k-state-selected').addclass('black')`